# Response map sort order with angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

From my server I return json

```
{
  "something":"a",
  "map": {
          "rowid":1,
          "a":1,
          "b":2,
          ..
          "r":2
          }
  }
```

When I use:

```
return this.authHttp.put(queryUrl, bodyString, this.requestsOptions).map(res=> res.json)
```

It returns the (observable json) object in sorted order:

```
{
  "something":"a",
  "map": {

          "a":1,
          "b":2,
          ..
          "r":2,
          "rowid":1,
          }
  }`
```

Is there any way to control the order in which json() reads the inner map? So that the response ordering is preserved?

(Without having to map to a new object type if possible)

Comment: Objects in JSON are not guaranteed ordered; if the order matters, use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the order from the response is already maintained but console.log sorts the map into alphabetical order